# How to calculate average by labels grouping with prometheus histograms?

Tags: performance, prometheus, promql

I have batched DB queries in my program and would like to measure the average time for batched queries to finish based on batch size, currently I have

```
rate(batched_query_duration_seconds_sum{job="myprogram"}[5m]) / rate(batched_query_duration_seconds_count{job="myprogram"}[5m])
```

that metric has the label `batch_size`, I think the correct query would be something like

```
rate by (batch_size) (batched_query_duration_seconds_sum{job="myprogram"}[5m]) / rate by (batch_size) (batched_query_duration_seconds_count{job="myprogram"}[5m])
```

but it's syntax error. How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
sum(rate(batched_query_duration_seconds_sum{job="myprogram"}[5m])) by (batch_size) / sum(rate(batched_query_duration_seconds_count{job="myprogram"}[5m])) by (batch_size)
```

Comment: in that case the @hldev asked for average, which would be `avg()` but the principle stays the same. By the way you can also put the by statement to the front which is easier to read `avg by (batch_size) (rate(...))` Documentation can be found here: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators